# How "Not" works in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I was reading a code piece in Prolog and I saw the below code :

```
r(a).
q(b).
p(X) :- not r(X)
```

Questions :

```
?-q(X), p(X)     // Result: b
?-p(X), q(X)     //  Result: no
```

So, why for **?-q(X), p(X)**  we get **"b"** and for **?-p(X), q(X)** which is exactly the same as **?-q(X), p(X)** we get **"no"** ?

Answer (score 2):

```
?-q(X), p(X)     // Result: b
```

`q(X)` eventually unifies with `q(b)`, which then calls `p(b)`, which calls `not r(b)`, which is true.

```
?-p(X), q(X)     //  Result: no
```

`p(X)` calls `not r(X)`, which causes `X` to unify with `a`, which causes the preceding clause to evaluate to `not r(a)`, which is false, and the conjuction operator short circuits to no.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the two queries are not *exactly the same* because Prolog "conjunction" operator (the comma) is usually not commutative:

1. the execution is from left to right and so the order in which the variables are instantiated is different in those queries
2. if you only use pure logical predicates, that is predicates that are defined not using extra-logical predicates (like `not/1` or if-then-else constructs), nor predicates having side-effects (like I/O ones), nor predicates that require some of its arguments to be instantiated beforehand (like `is/2`), the change in instantiation order does not affect commutativity
3. but as one of your predicates uses `not/1` and it behaves differently when its argument is `r(_)` or `r(b)` as explained in C.B. answer, commutativity does not hold.

As you may know `not/1` does not implement pure logical negation: it implements so-called *negation as failure* meaning that it succeeds if the execution of its argument fails and otherwise fails (if the argument is a free variable you get an instantiation error). As the execution is from left to right you cannot expect that its behaviour is affected by some instantiation made **after** its call.